# error occured when adding anotation to the java class

Tags: spring-mvc

Multiple markers at this line
- Repository cannot be resolved to a type
- The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type

Error gets when trying to add `@Repository("loginDAO")` to the `loginDAOImpl.java`. I don't use maven.

@Repository("loginDAO")
public class LoginDAOImpl implements LoginDAO {

```
 @Resource(name="sessionFactory")
 protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
 }

 protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
 }
public boolean checkLogin(String userName, String userPassword) {
    System.out.println("In Check login");
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    boolean userFound = false;
    //Query using Hibernate Query Language
    String SQL_QUERY =" from Users as o where o.userName=? and o.userPassword=?";
    Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
    query.setParameter(0,userName);
    query.setParameter(1,userPassword);
    List list = query.list();

    if ((list != null) && (list.size() > 0)) {
        userFound= true;
    }

    session.close();
    return userFound;
}
```

Comment: Please add relevant code as well.

Comment: which dependencies do you have in your classpath?